# Hierarchy of interfaces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is it considered bad to create a hierarchy of interfaces in Java?

I have designed my repository layer like this:

- `Repository`, contains CRUD methods
- `JPARepository`, potential methods that is only needed in JPA
- `SomeModelRepository`, specific methods for the repository of that model.
- `SomeModelJPARepository`, extends JPARepository AND SomeModelRepository

Is this considered bad practice, and is it a strange organized hierarchy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in fact it's fairly common to create interface hierarchies, at least in libraries.
Take [NavigableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) for instance, which has 4 layers of interfaces above it (SortedSet, Set, Collection, Iterable).

In this example, the diamond inheritance is a bit peculiar, but if necessary not a bad choice per se. But usually a tree hierarchy is much clearer and better. In this case I would consider making either:

1. SomeModelRepository a subclass of JPARepository, thus forcing all implementing classes to support JPA
2. Specifying the JPA support in a different interface, not a subclass from Repository. Then all classes could choose whether to implement JPA independent of their specific Repository interface. See [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for an example. This is the de facto solution for signalling that a class supports a specific feature like "serialization", or maybe "persistence" like in this case.

Comment: Rewrote answer to better answer the original question

Comment: Just one more question, I also have an abstract class that I use to implement the CRUD (generic class). It is not wrong to implement the Repository interface as I do now in the class? Or should I have added the CRUD directly in the class?

Comment: And are there any limit on how many interfaces a class could implement in terms of when it starts to smell bad?

Comment: Okay, one by one. You implementation of the abstract class is not bad. In fact it's common to have both an interface and implementing abstract class. That way your subclasses inherit from the abstract if they do not have a base yet buy just implement the interface if they do. You should however implement as much of the interface as it practical in the abstract class, otherwise it is useless.

Comment: Second question: there's no rule of thumb. Some standard java classes implement over 10 interfaces. As long as each interface is meaningful (e.g. has a defined meaning or useful methods) and applicable to that particular class there's no limit to how much interfaces a class can have. However, when a class implements a lot of interfaces you might want to consider dividing the class into multiple pieces as it might have to much responsibility (i.e. the code becomes to large and difficult)